# Error 13 en macro: no coinciden los tipos

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Al crear la siguiente macro para copiar, de una hoja a otra tan solo las celdas que cumplan la condición, la ejecución me muestra este error:

> "error '13': no coinciden los tipos"

Código:

```
Sub CondicionalTopTxx()

Dim OrigenHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
    DestinoHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
    a As Integer

Set OrigenHoja = Worksheets("TNC D")
Set DestinoHoja = Worksheets("TNC B")

OrigenHoja.Activate

    For a = 2 To 40

    Set valor = OrigenHoja.Cells(a, 17)

      If valor.Value < 4 Then

      Range("O14:S16").Copy
      DestinoHoja.Range("O14:S16").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

      End If

    Next

End Sub
```

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar tan solo el rango que cumple la condición?

Comment: Este error es porque no coinciden los datos. Una opción sería asegurarte que todos los valores son numéricos, la celda no tiene formato texto. ¿Podemos ver los datos? Otra opción puede ser que el valor que estás copiando venga de una fórmula que devuelva un error.

Comment: El objetivo de la macro es recorrer un columna y, solo si, cumple la condicion de ser <=3 copiar un rango a otra hoja

Comment: Necesitas crear un Loop que te compruebe cada valor individualmente.

Comment: Tengo una columna con datos. Esta se debe recorrer, y si el valor de alguna de las filas de la columna es igual o inferior a 3 se debe copiar un rango de celdas en otra hoja del mismo libro. Actualizo el código con lo que se me ha ocurrido. Disculpad si lo que veis es una absurda, no estoy muy puesto en bucles de macros.

Comment: Estoy hecho un lío.

Comment: En la pregunta original pego nuevo código. ¿Por qué no me evalua la condición?

Comment: @Calej Favor de agregar los datos que está tomando `OrigenHoja.Cells(a, 17)` incluyendo las filas y columnas que ocupan.

Comment: `OrigenHoja.Cells(a,17)` recoge en `valor` el value de cada iteración. Ese valor lo compara con la condición. Si la condicion se cumple (que sea menor que 4) entonces tiene que seleccionar un rango y copiar en un rango de otra hoja. Por ejemplo: La iteración 3 recoge en `valor` el dato de de la fila 3 columna Q. El contenido de `valor` es comparado, Al ser menor que 4 cumple la condición. En ese caso necesito que se copie el rango (O3:S3) al rango de la hoja destino (O14:S14). La siguiente iteración que cumpla la condición se debe copiar el rango (O15:S15).  Espero haber respondido correctam.

Comment: Tu código siempre copia el mismo rango de origen en el mismo rango de destino. No cambia en ningún momento. Leyendo tu explicación, entiendo que el Rango que quieres copiar va cambiando, pero ¿dónde lo quieres pegar? ¿Siempre lo vas a pegar en `(O14:S14)`? A la última en blanco? O lo vas a pegar siempre 11 filas por debajo? O como? Por ejemplo, dices que la iteración 3 copiaría `(O3:S3)` al rango `(O14:S14).` (de la hoja destino). Vale, imagínate que la siguiente iteración que cumple la condición es la 5. ¿Dónde copiarías el rango `(O5:S5)`

Comment: Además, tienes definida una variable llamada ´valor´ que no defines. ¿Qué tipo de variable es?

Comment: Perdon, por no aclarar mucho. Exacto, como bien has preguntado, la siguiente iteración que cumpla la condición se pegará en la siguiente en blanco. Es decir, si la primera se copia en `(O14:S14)` la siguiente se debe copiar en `(O15:S15)`. Y sí, la variable no está definida, se me pasó. La variable valor es un integer. Gracias

Comment: Hola Calej. Quisiera saber que es exactamente lo que quieres hacer y si mi respuesta te sirve de algo. No estoy seguro de si he contestado a tu cuestión aunque creo que sí.

Answer (score 3):

No está claro lo que quieres hacer pero sí está claro que uno de los problemas de tu procedimiento Sub es que `Worksheets("TNC B").Range("Q14:Q16").Value` devuelve un objeto de tipo Variant que es un array y luego lo comparas con un número ( `valor <= 3`)

Tal vez deberías usar un bucle para recorrer todos los valores del array.

Comment: El objetivo de la macro es recorrer un columna y, solo si, cumple la condicion de ser <=3 copiar un rango a otra hoja.

Comment: @Calej Con lo de recorrer se refuerza la idea de que debes usar un bucle sin embargo aún no queda aclara la condición. Agrega a tu pregunta algunos ejemplos de datos de entrada y salida.

Comment: Tengo una columna con datos. Esta se debe recorrer, y si el valor de alguna de las filas de la columna es igual o inferior a 3 se debe copiar un rango de celdas en otra hoja del mismo libro. Actualizo el código con lo que se me ha ocurrido. Disculpad si lo que veis es una absurda, no estoy muy puesto en bucles de macros.

Comment: Estoy hecho un lío.

Comment: En la pregunta original pego nuevo código. ¿Por qué no me evalua la condición?

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la manera en la que accedes a los rangos, así cuando escribes

```
    OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).Copy
    DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

y debido a como Excel gestiona las funciones y macros, se hace necesario añadir ***.Address*** siempre y cuando el dato a trabajar esté en una hoja distinta desde la que estamos ejecutando nuestra *Sub* o *Function*. Que sea o no la hoja activa no afecta (de hecho la línea **OrigenHoja.Activate** puede ser silenciada y el código seguirá funcionando perfectamente)

Por lo tanto si ***Sub CondicionalTopTxx()*** está escrita en la hoja ***TNC D*** el código será:

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Si ***Sub CondicionalTopTxx()*** está escrita en la hoja ***TNC B*** el código será:

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Si no tenemos esto en cuenta obtendremos un error ***1004 en tiempo de ejecución***. Si decidimos poner siempre ***.Address*** evitaremos problemas si copiamos esa función a otras hojas. El código que dejo lo hace así.

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, este código te funcionará perfectamente.
He cambiado algunos valores para hacer el ejemplo. Adáptalo a tus necesidades.

```
Sub CondicionalTopTxx()

Dim OrigenHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
DestinoHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
a As Integer

Set OrigenHoja = Worksheets("TNC D")
Set DestinoHoja = Worksheets("TNC B")

'OrigenHoja.Activate

    For a = 2 To 15
        Set valor = OrigenHoja.Cells(a, 5)
        If valor.Value < 4 Then
        OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).Copy
        DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Ejemplo real del código. A la iquierda las celdas con números aleatorios. A la derecha los rangos copiados a otra hoja que cumplen la premisa ***Columna < 4***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, la extraña forma en la que Excel gestiona estas referencias (directas o indirectas) requiere una serie de aclaraciones que nos ayudarán a evitar esos errores a los que Excel nos tiene acostumbrado.

Si la *Function* o *Sub* está en un módulo y la propiedad *.Address* no está aplicada en ninguna de las sentencias:

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

el código fallará en todos los casos. No importa si la llamamos desde una hoja u otra o desde el mismo módulo o desde un Sub o Function. Fallará y nos mostrará un ***error 1004… en el método ‘Range’ de objeto ‘_Worksheet’*** o un simple ***error 1004…***.

Si la propiedad *.Address* se encuentra solo en una de ellas (pongo un único ejemplo)

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

la función solo correrá si la hoja activa coincide con la hoja apuntada por la sentencia que hace referencia directa, en este caso

```
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

**La dinámica de este comportamiento conlleva una especial atención ya que según el lugar donde esté el código (objeto hoja, módulo) y la hoja activa en ese momento nos encontraremos con resultados distintos.**