# Ayuda en macro excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Necesito saber como, tras cumplir la condición, se puede copiar el rango correspondiente y pegar en otra hoja. Es decir, si la fila 13, tras llegar la iteración, cumple la condicion se copie el rango definido de la fila 13 y se copie en el rango definido de otra hoja.

```
Sub CondicionalTopTxx()

Dim OrigenHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
    DestinoHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
    a As Integer

Set OrigenHoja = Worksheets("TNC D")
Set DestinoHoja = Worksheets("TNC B")

OrigenHoja.Activate

    For a = 2 To 40

    Set valor = OrigenHoja.Cells(a, 17)

      If valor.Value < 4 Then

      Range("O14:S16").Copy
      DestinoHoja.Range("O14:S16").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

      End If

    Next

End Sub
```

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar tan solo el rango que cumple la condición?
Gracias.

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163180/error-13-en-macro-no-coinciden-los-tipos

Comment: He vuelto a publicar la pregunta porque no tenía respuesta en la anterior. Siento si he incumplido alguna norma.

Comment: El rango a copiar es móvil es decir cambia según va iterando? si es asi, como seria este cambio?

Comment: Si la iteración cumple con la condiciones siempre se copia el mismo rango de columnas, lo que cambia es la fila. Es decir, si el valor de "Valor" es menor que 4, y está en la iteración 7, se copia el rango "O7:S7". Si nos encontramos en la iteración 10, y cumple la condición, se copia el rango "O10:S10".

Comment: Hola Calej. Quisiera saber que es exactamente lo que quieres hacer y si mi respuesta te sirve de algo. No estoy seguro de si he contestado a tu cuestión aunque creo que sí.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que a es el numero de la fila en la que nos encontramos:

```
Range(Cells(a,15),Cells(a,19)).Copy
```

Con esto siempre se debería seleccionar el rango donde estas evaluando la condicion.

Comment: Corrijo mi anterior respuesta. Esta forma funciona si el codigo se lanza desde la misma hoja desde la que se quieren obtener los datos

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la manera en la que accedes a los rangos, así cuando escribes

```
    OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).Copy
    DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

y debido a como Excel gestiona las funciones y macros, se hace necesario añadir ***.Address*** siempre y cuando el dato a trabajar esté en una hoja distinta desde la que estamos ejecutando nuestra *Sub* o *Function*. Que sea o no la hoja activa no afecta (de hecho la línea **OrigenHoja.Activate** puede ser silenciada y el código seguirá funcionando perfectamente)

Por lo tanto si ***Sub CondicionalTopTxx()*** está escrita en la hoja ***TNC D*** el código será:

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Si ***Sub CondicionalTopTxx()*** está escrita en la hoja ***TNC B*** el código será:

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Si no tenemos esto en cuenta obtendremos un error ***1004 en tiempo de ejecución***. Si decidimos poner siempre ***.Address*** evitaremos problemas si copiamos esa función a otras hojas. El código que dejo lo hace así.

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, este código te funcionará perfectamente.
He cambiado algunos valores para hacer el ejemplo. Adáptalo a tus necesidades.

```
Sub CondicionalTopTxx()

Dim OrigenHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
DestinoHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
a As Integer

Set OrigenHoja = Worksheets("TNC D")
Set DestinoHoja = Worksheets("TNC B")

'OrigenHoja.Activate

    For a = 2 To 15
        Set valor = OrigenHoja.Cells(a, 5)
        If valor.Value < 4 Then
        OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).Copy
        DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Ejemplo real del código. A la iquierda las celdas con números aleatorios. A la derecha los rangos copiados a otra hoja que cumplen la premisa ***Columna < 4***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, la extraña forma en la que Excel gestiona estas referencias (directas o indirectas) requiere una serie de aclaraciones que nos ayudarán a evitar esos errores a los que Excel nos tiene acostumbrado.

Si la *Function* o *Sub* está en un módulo y la propiedad *.Address* no está aplicada en ninguna de las sentencias:

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

el código fallará en todos los casos. No importa si la llamamos desde una hoja u otra o desde el mismo módulo o desde un Sub o Function. Fallará y nos mostrará un ***error 1004… en el método ‘Range’ de objeto ‘_Worksheet’*** o un simple ***error 1004…***.

Si la propiedad *.Address* se encuentra solo en una de ellas (pongo un único ejemplo)

```
OrigenHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15).Address, Cells(a, 19).Address).Copy
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

la función solo correrá si la hoja activa coincide con la hoja apuntada por la sentencia que hace referencia directa, en este caso

```
DestinoHoja.Range(Cells(a, 15), Cells(a, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

**La dinámica de este comportamiento conlleva una especial atención ya que según el lugar donde esté el código (objeto hoja, módulo) y la hoja activa en ese momento nos encontraremos con resultados distintos.**

Comment: Como soy nuevo por aquí me gustaría saber la puntuación negativa por qué es. Creo haber solucionado el problema y lo correcto es decir en que me he equivocado para no volver a cometer el mismo error.

Comment: Si no he entendido el problema o he contestado a otra cosa, ayudaría saberlo.

Comment: Hola APO69, no soy el del voto negativo, pero veo que esta respuesta es idéntica a [otra que realizaste en una pregunta diferente]. Las respuestas duplicadas suelen ser una indicación de que algo está ocurriendo y generalmente se deben a o bien preguntas duplicadas (en cuyo caso habría que votar para cerrar una de ellas), o bien una de las respuestas realmente no aplica al caso expuesto en la pregunta. ¿Es esta pregunta similar a la otra en la que contestaste?

Comment: Hola Alvaro, gracias por la aclaración. Pues si, si que es idéntica solo que el encabezado y la manera de preguntar cambia. Si quieres buscar esa pregunta puedes hacerlo con: "Error 13 en macro: no coinciden los tipos". Verás que es un copy/paste. En cualquier caso, y perdona mi ignorancia, no creo que castigar una respuesta que soluciona un problema sea muy etico. El error está en quien pregunta. Ambas preguntas llevan más de 11 meses sin que nadie las haya eliminado y sin una respuesta concreta y cuando esa respuesta llega se sanciona al que da la solución. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Además, esta respuesta engloba una serie de problemas en los que muchos nos hemos visto sumergidos. Que una senténcia necesite tener una propiedad u otra en función del lugar desde el que se lanza es algo que necesitamos saber todos.

Comment: Me decepciona un poco ver un -1 en una respuesta de este tipo.